# Z and $\gamma$ bosons as mixtures of W and B: Part II

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, electroweak

When it is said that the photon is ["a mixture of W and B"][1] ($B$ being a gauge field associated with the $U(1)$ hypercharge)

I have one question on this:

- Why there isn't a boson directly generated by this $B$ gauge?

Comment: link to part I: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/477283/955

Comment: because $SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$ is broken down to $U(1)_{em}$. When the former symmetry is restored (early universe) there will be massless B boson, and also 3 massless W bosons.

Answer (score 0):

As Kosm suggests in his comment, there technically is a massless boson directly generated by the $B_\mu$ field. The reason we do not see it in (say) particle accelerators is because our universe is "too cold," and hence spontaneous symmetry breaking in the Higgs field generates the $A_\mu$ (photon), $Z_\mu$, and two $W^\pm_\mu$ fields.